# WebException on HTTP request while debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET project which involves sending HTTP requests via the Web-API Framework. The following exception is only raised when debugging:

> The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine

The project runs perfectly if I "Start Without Debugging".

How should I resolve this exception?

Any help is appreciated!

---

**Update**

The problem seems related to the ASP.NET MVC Identity Framework.

To access other Web-API methods, the client application has to first POST a **login** request (The login request does not need to be secure yet, and so I am sending the username and password strings directly to the Web-API POST method). If I comment out the login request, no more exception is raised.

Below are the relevant code snippets:

**The Post method:**

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
AccountAccess ac = new AccountAccess();

public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
{
    string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    LoginMessage msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginMessage>(result);
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var user = UserManager.Find(msg.username, msg.password);
    if (user == null)
        return response;
    if (user.Roles == null)
        return response;
    var role = from r in user.Roles where (r.RoleId == "1" || r.RoleId == "2") select r;
    if (role.Count() == 0)
    {
        return response;
    }
    bool task = await ac.LoginAsync(msg.username, msg.password);
    response.Content = new StringContent(task.ToString());
    return response;
}
```

**The Account Access class (simulating the default AccountController in MVC template):**

```
public class AccountAccess
{
    public static bool success = false;
    public AccountAccess()
        : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext())))
    {
    }

    public AccountAccess(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    public async Task<bool> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(username, password);
        if (user != null)
        {
             await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
             return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    ~AccountAccess()
    {
        if (UserManager != null)
        {
            UserManager.Dispose();
            UserManager = null;
        }
    }

    private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        }
    }

    private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
    {
        AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
    }
}
```

---

Below are the relevant code snippets:

**In client application:**

```
public static async Task<List<T>> getItemAsync<T>(string urlAction)
{
    message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    message.RequestUri = new Uri(urlBase + urlAction);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    List<T> msgs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(result);
    return msgs;
}
```

**In Web-API controller:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    if (id == "ItemA")
    {
        List<ItemAMessage> msgs = new List<ItemAMessage>();

        // some code...

        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgs));
    }
    else if (id == "ItemB")
    {
         List<ItemBMessage> msgs = new List<ItemBMessage>();

        // some code...

        response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgs));
    }
    return response;
}
```

Some observations I have:

1. I thought that I may need to send the request asynchronously (with the `async-await` syntax), but the exception still persists that way.
2. If I step through the code, the request **does** enter the HTTP method, but the code breaks at random line (Why?!) before returning the response, so I assume no response is being sent back.
3. I have tried the following solutions, as suggested in answers to similar questions, none of which works for me:

   - Setting `useUnsafeHeaderParsing` to `true`
   - Adding the header `Keep-Alive: false`
   - Changing the port setting of Skype (I don't have Skype, and port 80 and 443 are not occupied)

Additional information, in case they matter:

- Mac OS running Windows 8.1 with VMware Fusion
- Visual Studio 2013
- .NET Framework 4.5
- IIS Express Server

---

**Update 2**

The exception is resolved, but I am unsure of which modification did the trick. AFAIK, either one or both of the following fixed it:

- I have a `checkConnection()` method, which basically sends a GET request and return true on success. I added `await` to the `HttpClient.SendAsync()` method and enforced **async all the way up**.
- I retracted all code in the MainWindow constructor, except for the `InitializeComponent()` method, into the Window Initialized event handler.

Any idea?

Below are relevant code to the modifications illustrated above:

**the checkConnectionAsync method:**

```
public static async Task<bool> checkConnectionAsync()
{
    message = new HttpRequestMessage();
    message.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
    message.RequestUri = new Uri(urlBase);
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
        return (response.IsSuccessStatusCode);
    }
    catch (AggregateException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Window Initialized event handler (retracted from the MainWindow constructor):**

```
private async void Window_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (await checkConnectionAsync())
    {
        await loggingIn();
        getItemA();
        getItemB();
    }
    else
    {
        logMsg.Content = "Connection Lost. Restart GUI and try again.";
    }
}
```

---

**Update 3**

Although this may be a little off-topic, I'd like to add a side note in case anyone else falls into this – **I have been using the wrong authentication approach for Web-API to start with.** The Web-API project template already has a built-in Identity framework, and I somehow "replaced" it with a rather simple yet broken approach...

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk0PwKO4MP0) is a nice tutorial to start with.

[This article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) provides a more comprehensive explanation.

Comment: What happens if you remove the sleep call in LoginAsync?

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm I actually added that line to test something else and forgot to remove it when posting the code. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Is it possible the VM is adding to the issue?

Comment: Also try setting Keep-Alive to false.

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm The VM? How so? And one of the things I tried is actually setting Keep-Alive to false. I've edited it. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt it is this but the VM could be set to watch for http and act on it.  Another thing to check is the port used when debugging, make sure it is correct.  Are you using a windows client?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the port, and I'm using Windows 8.1 running on VMware Fusion, as stated in my question. The exception was somehow resolved. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

In the Client Application you are not awaiting `task`. Accessing Result without awaiting may cause unpredictable errors. If it only fails during Debug mode, I can't say for sure, but it certainly isn't the same program (extra checks added, optimizations generally not enabled). Regardless of when Debugging is active, if you have a code error, you should fix that and it should work in either modes.

So either make that function async and call the task with the `await` modifier, or call `task.WaitAndUnwrapException()` on the task so it will block synchronously until the result is returned from the server.

Comment: I actually have both versions (with and without await) of the getItem method, if that's the one you are referring to. Unfortunately, awaiting and ensuring "async all the way down/up" doesn't resolve the exception I am getting. Thanks for pointing out anyway! I have edited the code to avoid confusion.

Comment: I awarded the bounty to this answer since it points out the most possible cause of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure URL has ID query string with value either as Item A or Item B. Otherwise, you will be returning no content with Http status code 200 which could lead to protocol violation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `SendAsync`, you are required to provide all relevant message headers yourself, including `message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);` for example.
You might want to use `GetAsync` instead (and call a specific get method on the server).
Also, are you sure the exception is resolved? If you have some high level `async` method that returns a `Task` and not void, that exception might be silently ignored.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your last statement? As stated in the second update, I have modified the code to be "async all the way up", with the highest level (the event handlers) returning `void`. Every other async methods return `Task`.

Comment: As to the other point, should I use GetAsync with GET (or HEAD) requests and SendAsync for the rest?

Comment: I wanted to make sure that indeed there are no event handlers returning ´Task´ or other tasks that are not awaited.

Comment: Then I guess I'm safe on this one. Thank you for your input!

Comment: As to the other point, use SendAsync when you need to send a message with headers other than the default ones.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Just did some research. Thank you again!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that exception is related to the headers you sent. If you didn't change these, make sure to break on all common runtime exceptions (available through ctrl-d, e) and attach the debugger to the process hosting your server.

Comment: Hmm I didn't know you could do that. I'll definitely give it a try. Thanks!